# Can you cast the result of sizeof

Tags: c++, sizeof

I was wondering if it makes sense to cast the result of sizeof?
Example:

Change `sizeof(example)` to `(size_t) sizeof(example)`

The return type is `std::size_t`but I get the error "Invalid arguements" in many functions (malloc, memset, ...) and after the cast it works. A quick check with `printf` showed me, that the results stayed the same.

-edited- 
As requested a short example function:

```
   __cxa_dependent_exception* __cxxabiv1:: __cxa_allocate_dependent_exception()  throw()
    {
        __cxa_dependent_exception *ps_ret;

        ps_ret = static_cast<__cxa_dependent_exception *> (o_exception_pool.allocate (
                (size_t) sizeof(__cxa_dependent_exception )));

        if (!ps_ret)
        {
            std::terminate ();
        }

        memset (ps_ret, 0, (size_t) sizeof(__cxa_dependent_exception ));

        return ps_ret;
    }
```

Without the casts this code throws the mentioned error. The full example can be found in the gcc 4.5.4 source code "libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_alloc.cc" 
I am using MinGW.

Comment: I dropped the C tag: the question indeed makes no sense in C.

Comment: Can you give a minimal self-contained example to show why this is necessary?

Comment: @Brian 
`malloc(sizeof(t1))` "returns invalid arguements" with the cast the error is gone.

Comment: Can you provide a short, **complete** program that produces the error?

Comment: `sizeof` has the result `size_t`, so casting it has no effect. If this changes the program behaviour it indicates the program has undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question condenses to "can you cast `std::size_t` to another type".

Of course you can, subject to the normal type casting rules. For example, casting this to an `int` could get you in hot water for a very large type on a system with a 16 bit `int`. In other words, check that the new type has adequate capacity.

Extra brownie points if you can do that at *compile* time in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cast result of `sizeof`, since `sizeof(something)` is compile time and you will get result in type of `(size_t)5` if `sizeof(something)` returns `5`.